# Bash scripts that list folders with subfolder / folders with multiples files bigger than X

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm looking for a bash script, than can list all the folders, that have

***a) subfolders***

or

***b) more than 1 file bigger than size X***

Sadly my bash-fu is not that good to accomplish something like this, I wouldn't even know what to pipe together for something like this.

Regarding ***a)*** I have no idea where to start (fiddle with `ls -R`?)

Regarding ***b)*** I already can list all files bigger than size X with:

`du -sm * | awk '$1 > 500'`

But from there on, I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) `find` with `awk` and `sort`

```
$ find . -type d | awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{NF--} NF' | sort -u
```

find all directories, remove the last level, remaining ones are parents only with multiplicity, then filter.  Assumes no newlines in filenames.

For b) similarly

```
$ find . -size +1M | awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{NF--} NF' | sort -u
```

this is for greater than 1Mb, if you want 500b, change to `+500c`

Comment: Thanks a lot for a)

For b) I have expressed myself wrong. I want to list directories which have multiples files that are bigger than size X

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 1):

a) subfolders

```
find . -type d  | awk -F/ 'NF>2{print $2}' | sort -u
```

b) file size greater than 500mb

```
find . -type f -printf "%p %k\n" | awk '$NF>500000'
```